# Selecting rows from python array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. Let's say they look like this:

```
    time1 = [ 1 2 3 ] and time2 = [ 2 4 6]
            [ 4 5 6 ]         
            [ 7 8 9 ]
```

I would like to select only the rows from time1 for which the first column is within the range of time2. For example, from this data set, I would plot the [4 5 6] row, because 4 is in the range of 2 - 6. I am trying to select the rows from array time1 like this:

```
selectedtimes = time1(any(time1[:,0] < time2[-1]) and any(time1[:,0] > time2[0]))
```

I am currently receiving the object not callable error (shown below), and am quite stuck. Is there a better way to rewrite this line?

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) here:

```
>>> np.logical_and(time1[:,0] > time2[0], time1[:,0] < time2[-1] )
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> time1[np.logical_and(time1[:,0] > time2[0], time1[:,0] < time2[-1] )]
array([[4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` and `if`:

```
>>> time1 = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))
>>> time2 = (2,4,6)
>>> for x in time1:
...  if x[0] in time2:
...   print x
... 
(4, 5, 6)
>>>
```